# Can i make clicking on window will activate it but without bringing it to foreground?

Tags: windows-11, desktop-customization

Is there a way to disable bringing the window to foreground when be clicked? and then if i need it to come to foreground i use the taskbar or click over the specific window's title bar. and not by clicking any where else.

Is there a way to change this default behavior?

Note:
the programs that provide "hover over to activate" is not solving the problem. because i want to click while keeping it in back. so toggling the alignment of the windows will be mainly by the taskbar.

I am searching for "clicking window without bringing it to the foreground", I know that it is possible to make a window stay on top using third-party tools, but that isn't solving the issue, actually i search for tweak to keep all the windows not in top nor in back, just to stay wherever i place.

thanks for any help, bm3

Comment: Your title doesn’t really seem to properly summarize your question, perhaps that might be why you are having trouble finding answers. The active window is always in the foreground.

Comment: i updated the content, thanks for your advice

Comment: As @harrymc mentioned, AutoHotkey has some functionalities that might touch upon the fringe of what you're looking for, e.g., `ControlSend` can be used to "\[send\] simulated keystrokes to a window or control" without bringing the window to foreground or focus.  Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be an argument to circumvent the foreground behavior as it seems to be enforced on the OS-level, per `WinActivate`'s documentation, "When an inactive window becomes active, the operating system also makes it foremost (brings it to the top of the stack). "

Answer (score 1):

You can only paste into the active window, and the active window is
always in the foreground.

If you have a window that you wish to keep in the foreground even when
it's not active, you may set it to have the "topmost" or
(Always On Top) attribute.

This requires a third-party product, a random example is the free and
open-source
[MenuTools](https://github.com/navossoc/MenuTools),
or one of its
[alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/menutools/).

You may also program a tool such as
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)
to paste into the window under the cursor, even if that window is
not active.